# Bitcoin Cash Wallet options and receiving BCC

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cash

Is there a Bitcoin Cash wallet, that does not require the hole blockchain downloaded, already working? I tried Electron, but its very sketchy. Hopefully there will be one for iOS soon (Freewallet made it only for android).

When I generate a receive address, can it be used for multiple transactions, or only the first one that used it will "pass"?

Comment: It's better to ask only one question, to make answer easily searchable. There are already plenty of answers about reuse of addresses.

Answer (score 0):

There is Coinomi which runs on Android and soon on iPhone.

You can also run Coinimi in the Bluestack Android Emulator on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing addresses is a very bad practice. Avoid whenever possible. Consult: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address_reuse

Answer (score -1):

You can reuse your wallet address for multiple transactions. There are many wallets that support bitcoin cash. Ledger Nano S, Trezor, Jaxx, Electron Cash, Guarda, BTC.com, Coinomi.